# Trying to Login using web login page that is supported by firebase, then redirect to a home page

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am having trouble trying to login and redirect my website login page using firebase.
I want to sign in using saved email address and password on my firebase realtime database. I use Go To Console>Authentication>Users>Add Users, after saving I go to my login page then type the email address and password. I then want to be redirected to my dashboard.html page but I cant seem to figure out whats wrong after hours of debugging my code. I have also tried adjusting my sign-in method on firebase. I have a screenshot of it.[sign-in method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3JNK.png)

```js
(function(){
  // Initialize Firebase
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"
  var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //Get Elements
  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
  const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');
  const btnLogout = document.getElementById('btnLogout');

  //Add Login event
  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    //Get email and pass
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass =  txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //Sign in
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  //add signup event
  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    // TODO: CHECK 4 REAL EMAILZ
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass =  txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    //Sign in
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  });

  btnLogout.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  });

  //add a realtime listener
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
    if(firebaseUser) {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      btnLogout.classList.remove('hide');
      window.location.href == 'dashboard.html'
    } else {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      btnLogout.classList.add('hide');
      window.location.href == 'login.html'
    }
  });

}());
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: url(bg.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.loginbox{
 width: 320px;
 height: 420px;
 background:  #003300;
 color: #ffffff;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 70px 30px;
}

.techies{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: -50px;
 left: calc(50% - 50px);
}

h1{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 0 20px
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 22px;
}

.loginbox p{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.loginbox input{
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.loginbox input[type="usernametxt"], input[type="passwordtxt"]
{
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
 background: transparent;
 outline: none;
 height: 40px;
 color:#000000;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #000000;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submitbtn"]
{
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 height: 40px;
 background: #fb2525;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
.loginbox input[type="submitbtn"]:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
 background: #ffc107;
 color: #000;
}
.loginbox a{
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: darkgrey;
}
.loginbox a:hover
{
 color: #ffc107;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login Page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
 <div class = "loginbox">
  <img src="techies.jpg" class="techies">
  <h1>Login Here</h1>
  <form>
   <input id="txtEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

   <input id="txtPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password">

   <button id="btnLogin" class="btn-btn-action">Log In</button>

   <button id="btnSignUp" class="btn-btn-secondary">Sign Up</button>

   <button id="btnLogout" class="btn-btn-action hide">Logout</button>
  </form>
 </div>

<script src="loginjs.js"></script>

</body>
</head>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the output for console.log(firebaseUser) ,once the user is done with log-in?

Comment: im afraid i dont understan your question. after being authenticated and logging in it should redirect to my dashboard.html file. Did I answer your question? or do you want to see the dashboard.html file?

Comment: Was there any console log after the user log-ins?

Comment: on the tutorial he is using a local web server but i didnt use it in mine. When i click on "inspect element" and look at the console, there is no changes whatsoever. there is no error and there is no process happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem begins with

```
window.location.href == 'dashboard.html'
```

You're doing an equals comparison. Basically asking if the href is currently 'dashboard.html' Should be just one = for assignment

Then you have another problem... window.location.href needs to be a fully qualified address, so you're going to have to add the protocol, etc so it looks like 'http://.../dashboard.html'

```
window.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145322/trying-to-login-using-web-login-page-that-is-supported-by-firebase-then-redirec/55145515#55145515'
```

**EDIT**

Actually you can use location.assign relatively:

```
location.assign('./dashboard.html');
```

See [mdn doc for location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign)

Ah, apparently you can also do

```
location.href= './dashboard.html'
```

Doh... learned something new

**Another Edit**
This is how your onAuthStateChanged handler should look to work as intended

```js
//add a realtime listener
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser =>{
    if(firebaseUser) {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      btnLogout.classList.remove('hide');
      // window.location.href == 'dashboard.html' // Old Line
      window.location.href = './dashboard.html'; // Removed = and added ./
    } else {
      console.log(firebaseUser);
      btnLogout.classList.add('hide');
      // window.location.href == 'login.html' // Old Line
      window.location.href = './login.html'; // Removed = and added ./
    }
  });
```

Comment: I have tried changing the "==" sign to "=" but it still does not redirect me to the dashboard.html page

Comment: It has to be a full url. For ex, to redirect here see the example I added to my answer

Comment: i tried everything you said but it didn't work. i think i made the mistake somewhere in my javascript or html file. I tried this "window.location.href = "https://google.com"; " and it didnt redirect me to goole.com so i think my mistake is not in that part

Comment: try replacing window.location.href == 'dashboard.html' with window.location.href == './dashboard.html'. Without the './' the browser expects a full address. './dashboard.html' is a relative path

Comment: Take a look at https://www.lifewire.com/absolute-and-relative-paths-3466467

Comment: i got it to work using the method you described by switching the locations of './login.html' with './dashboard.html'. You are right it redirects my webpage and answers my question. however it automatically switches to my 'dashboard.html' and does not allow me to enter my password and email.

Comment: That's logical because your else clause is for when there is no user. You want to keep dashboard and login where they are, but you want to do the same thing to the login line you did for the dashboard line. I've added another snippet with how the code should look since I'm doing a bad job at explaining. How that helps.